# How to make an GWT server call(GWT RPC?)

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, rpc

Hi I am new to `gwt(java based gui)`.
Here i am trying to make a GWT server call.

I want to save my `MyBean` into my `Database`.

Later on i have to `update,delete etc..`

What are the possibilities and how can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of  possibilities to hit the database with GWT like `RequestFactory`,`RPC`.

Before getting started with server calls please go through,

- [GWT RPC](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC)(**Which makes server calls Asynchronesly**)
- [RequestFactory](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory)( **Alternative to GWT-RPC for creating data-oriented
  services.**)

After gone through the links here is a [Example of How to make an RPC](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Tutorials~RPC_To_Java).

Coming to your MyBean CRUD operations,**in short the simple RPC structure** as below :

```
GWT Code <===> InterfaceAsync <===> Interface (Synchronous)<===> Server Code
```

I am trying to explain with you elements it self .

**The Synchronous Interface(central to the whole RPC):**

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
public interface BeanProcessRPCInterface extends RemoteService
{
    public Mybean processMybeanRPC(Mybean  bean);
}
```

**The ASynchronous Interface(Key part on Client):**

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface BeanProcessRPCInterfaceAsync
{
    public void processMybeanRPC (Mybean bean, AsyncCallback callback);
}
```

Here you go with the **`Service`(Equals to servlet) which implements "BeanProcessRPCInterface"**

```
public class BeanProcessRPCImpl extends 
                   RemoteServiceServlet implements BeanProcessRPCInterface
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Mybean processMybeanRPC(Mybean  bean)
    {
       //Process your widget  here (CRUD operations)

    }

**you can override doget,doPost,doDelete....etc along with your methods 
}
```

**Map the above class in your web.xml;**

```
     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>beanrpc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.server.BeanProcessRPCImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>beanrpc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/beanrpc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Finally in your GWT Code .Use service as below

**Using in Code:**

*//register the service .*

```
   private final BeanProcessRPCInterfaceAsync beanService = 
        GWT.create(BeanProcessRPCInterface.class);
        ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service;
        endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint('beanrpc');
```

*requesting server with callback*

```
beanService.processMybeanRPC(mybean, callback);
 AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback()
    {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {
           //Do on fail
        }

        public void onSuccess(Object result)
        {
           //Process successfully done with result (result is which you
           // returned in impl class) .
        }
    };
```

P.S .Beware of package structures:

**BeanProcessRPCInterfaceAsync ,BeanProcessRPCInterface** should be in client* package

**MyBean** class should be in shared*  package

**BeanProcessRPCImpl**   should be in  server* package

Good Luck.