# Cannot find symbol GWTServiceAsync in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, gwt, netbeans

So, I'm new to GWT and I've just installed the plugin. I had all the dependency problems in the Universe (Since, apparently, all the real stuff does not come with the plugin), so I've downloaded GWT manually and added all the jars, and I've just created a new Maven/GAE/GWT/Whatever GWT project (Which was the only option available), and...... It does not work. I can't find GWTServiceAsync anywhere, not even in official docs. So, how can I import it?

[image]

Comment: Did you created that interface called ? `GWTServiceAsync`  ?

Comment: Nope, I've just created the project.

Comment: If you didn't get look at my example here  ":http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717089/how-to-make-an-gwt-server-callgwt-rpc/15717130#15717130

Answer (score 1):

It seems you directly using the names of the interface by seeing in examples.

You need to create those client side and server side interface and the corresponding implemented class as well.

If you are not understanding what I speaking, here is a complete example to create an RPC.

[How to make an GWT server call(GWT RPC?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717089/how-to-make-an-gwt-server-callgwt-rpc/15717130#15717130)